# Lighthouse metrics variance

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pagespeed-insights

please tell me why there is such a big difference between the included "Total Blocking Time" on the site https://developers.google.com/ and the local litehouse for a mobile device?

I am not able to give you the address and show you the site, there is just a text and a picture. The site is made on nuxt js and assembled completely statically.

My computer - mackbook air m1, google uses less powerful emulation and results in fewer parrots?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This official page explains it well: https://web.dev/performance-scoring/

##### Common problems:

- A/B tests or changes in ads being served
- Internet traffic routing changes
- Testing on different devices, such as a high-performance desktop and a low-performance laptop
- Browser extensions that inject JavaScript and add/modify network requests
- Antivirus software

---

Otherwise, this one is another answer: https://www.debugbear.com/blog/why-is-my-lighthouse-score-different-from-pagespeed-insights

Answer (score 0):

Google PageSpeed uses a “combo” of lab and real-world data[historical data of your website], whereas Lighthouse uses lab data only[locally tested on your machine] to build its report.

Note: You should trust PSI metrics over just lab data.

Comment: Both sets of data they are comparing are lab data, they don't have any page or origin data showing for the site. Page and Origin data has no impact on the score, they are there for diagnostics if available.